# How to union correctly Hashmap<String, ArrayList<Object>> and HashMap<String, Object>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I want to make my code clean add have the following trouble. I want add

`HashMap<String,Object> currentItem;`

to my storage

`HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> storage;`

by the following way:

Add all `Object` of `currentItem` to `ArrayList<Object>` of `storage` according to the keys (they all are the same).

This is my variant how to add currentItem to storage according to the keys

```
if (storage.containsKey("article_link")) 
{Object tmpObj;
    ArayList<Object> listTemp;
            tmpObj = currentItem.get("article_link");
        listTemp = storage.get("article_link");
        listTemp.add(tmpObj);
        storage.put("article_link", listTemp);

        tmpObj = o.get("image");
        listTemp = storage.get("image");
        listTemp.add(tmp);
        storage.put("image", rrr);
}
```

and this for each hashmap key. I can write special function for repeating code, but I hope it can be solved more easier.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check for null after calling `listTemp = output.get()`.  It is possible that the currentItem Map contains keys that are not present in the output Map.

Comment: What you need is not clear but you might be interested by guava's MultiMap (which are essentially some `Map<K, List<V>>`.

Comment: @user949300 Update code. Sorry "output" this is my "storage"

Comment: o.k., but whatever you name it, unless you are sure that the key already exists in storage, you should check for null and, if needed, create a new listTemp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note here is that, you don't need to put the mapping for new arraylist again, once you modify it. The changes will be reflected in the `Map` automatically, since, what you are having is the reference to the actual `ArrayList` object.

Secondly, you don't need to do all that `hard-coding`. You can simply iterate over your `currentItem` map, and for each `key-value` pair, check the existence of `key` in `storage`, and if found, just update the corresponding `List`.

Here's how you do that: -

```
for (Entry<String, Object> entry: currentItem.entrySet()) {
    if (storage.containsKey(entry.getKey()) {
        storage.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue());

    } else {
        List<Object> newEntry = new ArrayList<Object>();
        newEntry.add(entry.getValue());
        storage.put(entry.getKey(), newEntry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. But in this case we must use "add" instead of "put". Whatever, thanks.

Comment: Yes, should be an add().  And, if storage does not contain the key, you probably want to create a new List (as in the two other answers).  Finally, consider synchronizing this method.  Messy things could happen if two different threads are adding to storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Entry<String, Object> entry: currentItem.entrySet()) {
    if (!storage.containsKey(entry.getKey()) {
        storage.put(new ArrayList<Object>());
    }
    storage.get(entry.getKey()).put(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Entry<String,Object> entries = currentItem.entrySet();
Iterator<Entry<String,Object>> i = entries.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String,Object> e = i.next();
    if(storage.containsKey(e.getKey()) { 
        storage.get(e.getKey()).add(e.getValue());
    }
    else {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(e.getValue());
        storage.put(e.getKey(),l);
    }
}
```